# Let V be an n-dimensional vector space, and T from V to V a linear transformation...

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, nilpotence

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space, and $T$ from $V$ to $V$ a linear transformation. Show that $T$ is nilpotent of order $n$ if and only if there exists a basis $\beta = {v_1,v_2,....v_n}$ of $V$ such that the matrix of $T$ relative to $\beta$ is of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0... & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1... & 0 \\ \vdots& \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\ 0& 0 & 0... & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0... & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ (Sorry i can't figure out how to show the "..." vertically!)

I know that because it says "if and only if" i have to show both ways. I started assuming that $T$ is nilpotent, knowing this means the eigenvalues are zero, and trying to show there existed a basis of V such that the matrix of $T$ relative to $\beta$ is of that form, but i'm not sure how to show that the basis would be relative to $\beta$? I think i'm a little confused on how to approach this.

Comment: For vertical dots use `\vdots`, and for diagonal dots `\ddots`.

Comment: What's the matrix of $T^n$ relative to $\beta$, if $T$ relative to $\beta$ is of that form? This is hint is for one way...

Comment: Wouldn't the matrix be the same but the 1's move? So $T^n$ would just have a 1 in the upper right hand corner?

Comment: No,...Do it for $3$ by $3$. $T^2$ has the first one in the third column and ....

Comment: Would $$T^2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ ?

Comment: So then would $T^n$ be all zeros since $T^{n-1}$ would have the one in the top right hand corner?

Comment: Yes, in the 3 by 3 case the first one for T should be in the second column, then it moves, by 3 you're left with no 1.

Comment: Okay, so how do I relate this to what i'm supposed to prove?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37433/discussion-between-aboat-and-user319635).

Comment: I don't think it's worth writing an answer since you could do it, join the chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $T$ is a nilpotent of order $n$, then there exists a nonzero vector 
$v_n\in V$ such that $T^n(v_n)={\it 0}$ and $T^i(v_n)\ne{\it 0}$
for all $1\leq i\leq n-1$. So we consider the set 
$$\beta=\left\{T^{n-1}(v_n),T^{n-2}(v_n),\ldots,T(v_n),v_n\right\}$$
and we show that $\beta$ is the desired ordered basis for $V$. First,
we claim that $\beta$ is linearly independent. Given the scalars 
$a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^na_iT^{n-i}(v_n)={\it 0}.$$
Then
$${\it 0}
=T^{n-1}({\it 0})
=T^{n-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_iT^{n-i}(v_n)\right)
=\sum_{i=1}^na_iT^{2n-i-1}(v_n)
=a_nT^{n-1}(v_n),$$
it follows that $a_n=0$ and original equation becomes
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_iT^{n-i}(v_n)={\it 0}.$$
Then we use the same way to observe
$${\it 0}
=T^{n-2}({\it 0})
=T^{n-2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_iT^{n-i}(v_n)\right)
=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_iT^{2n-i-2}(v_n)
=a_{n-1}T^{n-1}(v_n),$$
which follows that $a_{n-1}=0$. Continue the process we may deduce that $a_i=0$ for each $i$, and hence $\beta$ is linearly independent, as
claimed. Since $V$
is $n$-dimensional, $\beta$ is actually an ordered basis for $V$. Finally, denote $v_i=T^{n-i}(v_n)$ for $1\leq i\leq n-1$,
it is clear that $T(v_{i+1})=v_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n-1$, and thus
$$[T]_\beta=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&0&1&\cdots&0&0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&1\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The converse is immediate.